# How do i save data in mongodb with one field as primary key

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I have a flask service running which connects to mongodb to save user info. When I want to save a user info I first check whether a user exists with that user name and then will add entry into the mongodb. Now my question is there any chance by which after I checked I db another entry was created before the corresponding entry was added.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is very little chance, anyway are you using unique index (on the username) to enforce the uniqueness at the mongodb level ?

Something like this should make you feel safer:

```
db.users.ensureIndex( { "username": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Comment: This works if data exists in a single monogo instace but what if I use Sharding

Comment: There are ways to enforce uniqueness across sharded collections, they are two options that i know of, they are described here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enforce-unique-keys-for-sharded-collections/, basically you can shard collection with unique constraint: `db.runCommand( { shardCollection : "users" , key : { username : 1 } , unique : true } );`